# Comment upon down voting a question on stack-overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

Apologies if this is not the correct platform for asking this. I recently got my question down voted, now under normal circumstances a developer would not just post a question unless they think they have exhausted all the other resources like asking co-developers(mostly seniors of course). My question was down voted but that person did not bother to maybe add a comment to say why.

I was wondering if is there perhaps a way of forcing someone to at least leave a comment after a down vote, I understand a down vote means the voter thinks a question is not well put or no enough research was done prior to the question being asked so at least a person should be able to leave a comment maybe a link that points to an answer to that very same question(especially the one answered on the very same stack overflow site), that why I can see how lazy or stupid I am for not seeing an answer that is right under my nose.

Comment: Btw a feature-request for forcing comments on downvotes has been suggested several times on MSO (Meta Stack Overflow), but all were declined, for similar reasons Oded already stated in his answer. That's why you also get downvotes on your feature-request here.

Comment: See [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/307988) and its many linked questions

Comment: `under normal circumstances a developer would not just post a question unless they think they have exhausted all the other resources`  You'd hope so, but this is so rarely true, as is the case for your own question here.  Clearly you spent no effort at all searching for an answer to this question before posting it, not exhausting *any* of the resources available to you to get your answer.  Hence the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if is there perhaps a way of forcing someone to at least leave a comment after a down vote

No, there isn't. This is by design.

---

We do not want to put barriers in front of voting, as that would immediately cause a drop in votes. This is bad because votes are our first and best signal to post quality - and a drop in votes would cause that signal to drop as well.

I cannot speak as to why your post was downvoted, but take it as a signal that there's something not right with it (though - some people will just downvote anything). Do not take it personally, but go back to the post and see what you can do to improve it.

---

Edit:

Assuming [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537460/what-does-adding-the-existing-project-to-the-current-solution-really-do-in-visua), the first comment there suggests that you could have done some research on this yourself - trying it out and seeing what happens, before you asked it on Stack Overflow. This suggests that the downvote was due to lack of research on your part.

Comment: Well I wasn't hurt by the down vote per se(though it took down my reputation), I was just devastated by the fact that theproblem is till not solved yet instead of someone trying to assist me they down vote instead, [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653224/mvc-app-works-fine-in-chrome-firefox-but-not-in-ie11)

Comment: You shouldn't take downvotes perosnally - you are not your post (with apologies to [Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/YouAreNotYourCode.aspx)).

Comment: In regards to your linked question - you have a bug that is reproducible. Open your developer tools **before** the issue shows up, put in a breakpoint where you think your code should start running, then trigger the issue.

Comment: A downvote is an attempt to help you, it's a signal that your question has problems, instead of ignoring it accept the help and improve the quality of your question.  Instead of editing your question, you replied with a comment, this means anyone who voted your question down still cannot reverse their vote.

Comment: @Ronny I checked the question _MVC app works fine in chrome, Firefox but not in IE11_ You said that it is not working. But didn't added any code. In order to reproduce the issue, people need the code. They can give you a solution only if they are able to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, it'll be considered as too broad and your post already have a close vote.

Comment: @Ramhound I hear you and appreciate that someone is trying to help but how does one get to improve their question if they dont see anything wrong with it, I mean take my question for example(check the link on my first comment), the app is working on 2 browsers but not on IE, the only improvement I can think of is the change in wording on the question since I cannot pin-point anything wrong on the code

Comment: @Ronny - you think there is nothing to improve? Never mind there's nothing wrong with it - there is always something to improve (add details, cleanup the phrasing, correct spelling/grammar, say what else you tried, say what has failed you).

Comment: @Ronny - you didn't post *any code*.

Comment: @Sagar that is exactly my point, l even mention in the question that I am not sure which part of code to provide because I cannot pin-point any part that might be causing the problem, in my experience on SO, whenever I posted the question I added the piece of code that is having issues, however in this specific instance it was difficult because I did not know what piece is problematic and mind you there is no error, none whatsoever. Or was I supposed to send the entire code from the app(that too might be considered vague)

Comment: Take the very same question we are discussing here, you see it has been down voted already but someone had a courtesy of marking it as duplicate, this shows exactly why the down vote, but on the question I asked about the MVC app, there are no comments as to why the down votes. The point here is not about reputation or being hurt by down votes but I am rather trying to find out if we can find a way to help others identify their problems with their questions, as well as making them improve their questioning ability on the SO platforms

Comment: "that is exactly my point, l even mention in the question that I am not sure which part of code to provide because I cannot pin-point any part that might be causing the problem" - This means from a SO viewpoint, you have not flesh out the problem far enough, how can you expect us to identify the block of code (and what is wrong with the block of code) if you cannot even provide us the block of code responsible for the unwanted behavior.  You did get feedback, and you replied to it as a comment, instead of editing the question.

Comment: "Or was I supposed to send the entire code from the app" - You are suppose to identify the block of code that reproduces the error, then provide the smallest subset of that code, that also reproduces it.

Comment: Don't post full code. Always add MCVE. please read the tour, mcve and ask of SO @Ronny

Comment: @Ramhound ok guys, I'll just leave it at that, seems to me you not getting my point, one can only provide a piece of problematic code only if it is there but if you not getting any error then how would you know that this is the piece that is giving you tough times, I mean you debug, you open dev tools but still cannot see the error. Yes this might mean the question is not well put but a mere down vote will not help someone improve their questioning skill in any way, thank you so much for time and input though :)

Comment: @Ronny No, **you** aren't getting the point.  You need to provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem for us to help you.  We can't help you at all if you don't do that.  If you can't provide us with what we need to help you *that doesn't change the fact that you haven't provided us with what we need to help you*.

Comment: @servy - I believe the OP is having problems even identifying the area of code causing problems. Arguably he should have asked about that in the SO question.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I'm aware that they're having problems figuring out what their question is even asking.  Like I said in my answer, *we can't help them if they can't even figure out what their question is*.  They're simply not yet at a point where they *can be helped*.  That they don't know how to ask an appropriate question doesn't make the question any more appropriate.

Comment: @Ronny - I go back to the fact, you have received feedback, but have made no modifications to the question (except add a tag) but only submitted a comment.